# Убрать div с помощью ajax и затем показать

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

При выборе radio нужно асинхронно убрать блок div, не получается. Вот:

```
<form method="post" action="">    
    <label for="rrr"><input id="rrr" type="radio" class="tr" name="dostavka" value="<?=$item['dostavka_id']?>" /><?=$item['name']?></label>    
</form>
```

Что нужно удалить:

```
<div class="notauth">
    <label>ФИО:</label> <input class="zakaz-inpt" type="text" name="name_zakaz">
</div>
```

Вот что мне уже помогли переделать на правильный код:

```
$(".tr").click(function(e){       
    var rrr = $("#rrr").val();
    $.ajax({
       url: './',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {rrr: rrr},
       success: function(){ $(".notauth").fadeOut(500); 
          setTimeout(function(){
               $(".notauth").remove();
          }, 500);
        },
       error: function(){
            alert("Error!");
       }
    });
});
```

Теперь отлично удаляет div при выборе нужного radio, но вот вопрос: а как возвратить обратно div, если выбрали другой radio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может https://api.jquery.com/detach/ ?

```
<div id="noauth_placeholder">
    <div class="notauth">
        <label>ФИО:</label> <input class="zakaz-inpt" type="text" name="name_zakaz">
    </div>
</div>

var $noauth;
$(".tr").click(function(e){       
    var rrr = $("#rrr").val();
    $.ajax({
       url: './',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {rrr: rrr},
       success: function(){ 
          $(".notauth").fadeOut(500, function() {
              $noauth = $(".notauth").detach();
          }); 
        },
       error: function(){
            alert("Error!");
       }
    });
});
```

И чтоб вернуть обратно

```
$('#notauth_placeholder').append($noauth);
```

Comment: Спасибо) Но что-то не получается, не работает)

Comment: а тут работает? http://jsfiddle.net/hjnL8668/2/

Comment: Все отлично работает, что-то сразу не подумал, что вместо `if(checkedVal == 'hide')` можно указать `if(checkedVal == 4)`, то есть id нужного radio, по клику которого и будет скрываться поле. Большое Вам спасибо. .

Answer (score 1):

Может надо не удалить а скрыть?

```
 $(".notauth").hide();
 $(".notauth").show();
```

Comment: а вот если просто скрыть, то просит заполните обязательное поле, так как у меня стоит в нем required="required", как  обойти это?)
еще там ошибся в вопросе, вот: "Теперь отлично удаляет div при выборе нужного radio, но вот вопрос: а как возвратить обратно div, если выбрали другой radio?"

Comment: Значит надо присвоить $(".notauth") или $(".notauth").html() какой-нибудь глобальной переменной, а когда потребуется использовать эту переменную (или через .html() или через .append(), например).

Comment: Можешь показать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделай связку по data-аттрибутам между нужными DIV'ами и RADIO. Тогда будет легко проверить, что если выбран radio_такой-то, то скрыть div_такой-то, иначе - показать.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score -1):

Может как-то так попробовать?
http://jsfiddle.net/6shsvx00/

Форма:

```
<input  type="radio" class="tr" name="dostavka" data-num="1">1</input>
<input  type="radio" class="tr" name="dostavka" data-num="2">2</input>
<input  type="radio" class="tr" name="dostavka" data-num="3">3</input>
<div data-num="1">1</div>
<div data-num="2">2</div>
<div data-num="3">3</div>
```

Стиль:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tr").click(function(){
        var tr = $(this);
        var num = tr.attr("data-num");
        $("div[data-num]").hide();
        $("div[data-num="+num+"]").show();
    });
})
```

Comment: Включайте код в ответ. Ссылка может протухнуть.

Comment: @user1562184  , Спасибо) А вот, как мне перечислить в div-е: `<div data-num="1, 2, 3, 4" >` просто мне надо убирать div только при одном radio.